# cloned a branch modified it, pushed it to my own branch but github folders are not accessible

Tags: git, github

I cloned a branch, modified the code, then used

```
git remote set-url origin git@github.com:USERNAME/REPOSITORY2.git
git add -A
git commit -am "Pushing code"
git push origin
```

there are 3 folders in it.

but when I go browse my branch, I can not click on those folders. git status doesn't show anything new and git remote -v shows my branch.

The main folder is a main github branch I have and the individual folders are clones of other repos. I just want to have all those files on my main github branch. How can I accomplish that?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Fixed it by running git rm --cached on the path on those directories and removing .git in those sub directories